# Allow JWT Tokens if Expired, Provided User is from Trusted IP address

Tags: ip, whitelist, flask-jwt-extended

Using flask-jwt-extended, I have a situation where the API has to serve both users, and also a series of web-applications (for example, one of the latter is a chatbot).

For the users, the package functionality out of the box is just perfect, however, for the web applications, I would like the JWT tokens to behave more like API-keys, where they don't necessarily expire after a period of time.

So what I would like to do, is to suppress the checks for 'expiry' provided the request has come from a predefined and trusted IP address.

I have a sqlalchemy model that stores trusted 'ip addresses', and this has a foreign key relationship with the users model, meaning that a user can specify one (or more) whitelisted ip addresses.

Now the `decode_token` function:

https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/flask_jwt_extended/utils.html#decode_token

Has an argument `allow_expired`, which permits the expiry to be overridden, however, this is not utilised in any way within the `_decode_jwt_from_request(...)` function, which seems to be instrumental when validating JWT tokens.

Ultimately, I am after a decorator replacement to `@jwt_required`, which permits expired tokens to be used, provided the request is coming from the whitelisted IP address.

My questions are twofold:

1. Is the above structure ok from a security point of view?, and,
2. Without having to duplicate (and slightly modify) entire functions from the library, how might I go about the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless anyone tells me a better way to do it, I ended up monkey patching the `decode_token` function:

I have highlighted the 'patched' region, which intercepts the 'ExpiredSignatureError', and checks if the ip address is in the user ip-whitelist, and if so, permits business as usual.

```
def decode_token(encoded_token, csrf_value=None, allow_expired=False):
    """
    Returns the decoded token (python dict) from an encoded JWT. This does all
    the checks to insure that the decoded token is valid before returning it.

    :param encoded_token: The encoded JWT to decode into a python dict.
    :param csrf_value: Expected CSRF double submit value (optional)
    :param allow_expired: Options to ignore exp claim validation in token
    :return: Dictionary containing contents of the JWT
    """
    jwt_manager = _get_jwt_manager()
    unverified_claims = jwt.decode(
        encoded_token, verify=False, algorithms=config.decode_algorithms
    )
    unverified_headers = jwt.get_unverified_header(encoded_token)
    # Attempt to call callback with both claims and headers, but fallback to just claims
    # for backwards compatibility
    try:
        secret = jwt_manager._decode_key_callback(unverified_claims, unverified_headers)
    except TypeError:
        msg = (
            "The single-argument (unverified_claims) form of decode_key_callback ",
            "is deprecated. Update your code to use the two-argument form ",
            "(unverified_claims, unverified_headers)."
        )
        warn(msg, DeprecationWarning)
        secret = jwt_manager._decode_key_callback(unverified_claims)

    try:
        return decode_jwt(
            encoded_token=encoded_token,
            secret=secret,
            algorithms=config.decode_algorithms,
            identity_claim_key=config.identity_claim_key,
            user_claims_key=config.user_claims_key,
            csrf_value=csrf_value,
            audience=config.audience,
            issuer=config.issuer,
            leeway=config.leeway,
            allow_expired=allow_expired
        )
    except ExpiredSignatureError:
        expired_token = decode_jwt(
            encoded_token=encoded_token,
            secret=secret,
            algorithms=config.decode_algorithms,
            identity_claim_key=config.identity_claim_key,
            user_claims_key=config.user_claims_key,
            csrf_value=csrf_value,
            audience=config.audience,
            issuer=config.issuer,
            leeway=config.leeway,
            allow_expired=True
        )


        # ------------------------------------------------------------
        # Author:   Nicholas E. Hamilton
        # Date:     25th August 2019
        # Patch:    Check if ip address is in the whitelist,
        #           and if so, permit an expired token
        # ------------------------------------------------------------
        user = user_loader(expired_token[config.identity_claim_key])
        ip_address = request.remote_addr
        if user and ip_address:
            ip_whitelist = [x.ip_address for x in user.ip_whitelist]
            if ip_address in ip_whitelist:
                return expired_token
        # >>>> END PATCH

        # Proceed as normal
        ctx_stack.top.expired_jwt = expired_token
        raise

flask_jwt_extended.view_decorators.decode_token = flask_jwt_extended.utils.decode_token = decode_token
```